# I am trying to make a program which tells a person what is a day (eg. monday or etc) after adding n numbers of days (in integer) in it

Tags: c++, days

So the program should ask a day as an input then it should represent it as an integer value (eg. 
 0 = Sunday or 1 = Monday and etc) then the user enters n number of days (like say 10 days) and the program has to find what day(from Sunday to Saturday) is after 10 days. (I know I can solve it using loop pretty easily but I am preferring not to use it, thanks.)

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    int main() {

        std::string today;
        std::cout <<"What day is today: " << std::endl;
        std::getline (std::cin, today);

        int d_ay;
        std::cout << "How many days to add ";
        std::cin >> d_ay;

        if (today == "Monday" or 1){
            today = 1 or "Monday";
        } 

        if (today == "Tuesday"){
            today = 2;
        }

        if (today == "Wednesday"){
            today = 3;
        }

        if (today == "Thursday"){
            today = 4;
        }

        if (today == "Friday"){
            today = 5;
        }

        if (today == "saturday"){
            today = 6;
        }

        if (today == "Sunday"){
            today = 0;
        }

        int meet;

        if(d_ay > 6){

            if (d_ay > 20){
                meet = (today + d_ay)/6;
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

This is how far I have got.

Comment: have look at operator `%`, which gives you the remainder of an integral division (e.g. `int result = (today + d_ay) % 7`

Answer (score 3):

Since the cycle of `"Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday"` *repeats* every 7 days, you only need 7 cases for `d_ay`.

However, this process can be made even more elegant by using the concept of `modulo`. Mods are represented by the `%` symbol in C++, and they are defined such that:
`a % b = the remainder when a is divided by b.`

For example, `4 % 3 = 1` and `4 % 2 = 0`.

Now, we can write a revised program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector <string> days = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
                            "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

    // Input
    string today;
    cout << "Enter today: ";
    cin >> today;

    int increment;
    cout << "Enter the increment: ";
    cin >> increment;

    cout << days[(i + increment)%7] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would just make an array of strings for each day of the week and create a placement unit variable like an int to keep track of where u are. So for example monday would be unit 1 because the week starts on sunday. Just add how ever many days to the index and if the new day is over 7 than just find the remainder after you divide it by seven. Then just print out the day of the week with the index number showing which day of the week it is in the array.